# ts-node TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using `ts-node` but it is giving me this error:

```
$ ts-node index.ts

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /home/projects/node-hddds8/index.ts
```

I tried to remove `"type": "module"` from my `package.json` but in that case I get a different error:

```
$ ts-node index.ts

(node:45) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/projects/node-hddds8/index.ts:1
import chalk from 'chalk';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Here is a reproduction link on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-hddds8?file=index.ts

My **package.json** looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "node-starter",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

And my **tsconfig.json** looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
  }
}
```

And my **index.ts** looks like this:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';

console.log(chalk.blue('Hello world!'));
```

Comment: I think this is just a specific problem caused by chalk being esm only. downgrade to `"chalk": "^4.1.2",`

Answer (score 25):

Since you have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` you are using ESM modules, therefore you need to add this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext" // or ES2015, ES2020
    },
    "ts-node": {
        // Tell ts-node CLI to install the --loader automatically
        "esm": true
    }
}
```

Comment: With this we have to always use .js extension in our imports, correct? Is there any way around that?

Comment: @AndyOh Yes, when using ESM modules it is mandatory to provide the file extension. See [docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions).  **But**, you can try the flag `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` to avoid having to always add .js to your imports.

Answer (score 9):

While the solutions with `ts-node-esm` or adding `esm: true` to the ts-node options in tsconfig works with "older" node versions, with node >= 20, this fails again with `ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION`.

A workaround is to use `node --loader` as described in [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997#issuecomment-1537111441):

```
node --no-warnings=ExperimentalWarning --loader ts-node/esm file.ts
```

Comment: Weirdly even though I'm using node 18.19.0, this is what I needed to get it to work as well. Thanks!

Comment: I believe node 18.19 got some updates from node 20 so the issue is introduced there too now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ts-node/esm loader swallows the stracktraces: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn370WEIvjs&t=600s

Answer (score 6):

Try to start your project with `ts-node-esm index.ts`

Answer (score 1):

After wrestling with this for many hours, I finally settled on [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx).

```bash
$ npm install --save-dev tsx
```

And then in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsx watch src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, tsx doesn't provide type checking capabilities: https://youtu.be/jn370WEIvjs?si=lbN2nhkXGuC5vS9l&t=810

Answer (score 1):

When using **Node.js 18, ts-node and ESM**, you can use:

- `ts-node index.ts`
- `node --loader ts-node/esm index.ts`
- `node --no-warnings=ExperimentalWarning --loader ts-node/esm index.ts` (if you want to suppress experimental warnings)

When using **Node.js 20, ts-node and ESM**, you cannot use `ts-node-esm` anymore (it will show you `ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION`). You have to use:

- `node --loader ts-node/esm src/main.ts`

Unfortunately, this approach does not provide stack traces. Therefore, in the case of a compiler error, you will only see:

> internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException

You can work around this by using a combination of `tsc` and `ts-node` such as:

- `tsc --noEmit && node --loader ts-node/esm index.ts`

Alternatively, you can use [tsimp](https://github.com/tapjs/tsimp):

- `TSIMP_DIAG=error node --import=tsimp/import index.ts`

I also made a tutorial showing each step:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn370WEIvjs

Comment: is there any solution for automatically restarts  node application when it detects any changes? can't use nodemon instead  of node

Comment: is there a boilerplate project? it seems insane we have to hunt this far to get a working typescript project in 2024.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because your compilerOptions in typescript is set to `{“module”: “esnext”}`, so its getting interpreted as a module by ts-node. Try changing it to `{“module”: “CommonJS”}`